# Convert a void* back into an array

Tags: c++, windows, pointers

I have a `char*` array which gets converted to `void*`, but I am having difficulty accessing the original array. See the `args` array:

```
void run_async(char* src, char* dest) {
  char* args[] = {src, dest};
  _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, copyFile, args, NULL, 0);
}

unsigned __stdcall copyFile(void* args) {
  char* src = (char*)((char*)args)[0]; //!Not correct
}
```

My mind is having trouble wrapping around these pointers. How do I access array location 0 and 1 in the `copyFile()` function?

Edit: On [coderpad](http://codepad.org/iGI9aRHR) the function works with the updated cast (char**) but during program execution with threadding it does not

Comment: You want to cast `args` to a `char**`. And then the index operator already returns a `char*`, so there's no need to cast that again. `char* src = reinterpret_cast<char**>(args)[0];`

Comment: @AndreasWenzel When I do that, the src variable contains "-64 'A'"

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with actual output and expected output.

Comment: Thanks, it's working when I use coderpad, not sure why my debugger has garbled output. http://codepad.org/iGI9aRHR Make as an answer so I can accept

Comment: Meanwhile, I have merged both of my comments into one answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must cast `args` to `char **`, because `args` is a pointer to the first element, which itself is a `char *`. So you have a so-called "double pointer", i.e. a pointer to a pointer. After that, you can use the `[]` subscript operator on it, and the second type cast is unnecessary.

The reason why the code you linked to in the comments section works, but the code in your original question doesn't, is probably the following reason: The [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) of the array `args` in the function `run_async` is limited to the lifetime of the function `run_asyc`. You therefore have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). If the function `run_async` exits before `copyFile` reads the array, then the array may have meanwhile been overwritten by something else.

To prevent this race condition, you should ensure that the lifetime of the array exceeds that of the thread created by `_beginthreadex`, for example by

1. using a global array (simplest solution, but sometimes considered bad programming practice), or
2. allocating the array in the function `main` instead of `run_async`, or
3. allocating the array with [`new[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) or [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) and only calling `delete[]` or `free` after the second thread has terminated, or by making the second thread responsible for calling `delete[]` or `free` when the array is no longer required.

However, as pointed out in the comments section, using a C-style array and calling the function `_beginthreadex` is not the ideal way to solve your problem in modern C++. If you use [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead of `_beginthreadex` and use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of a C-style array, then you can simply pass the array by value to the new thread. That way, you don't have to worry about freeing the memory of the array, because there is no dynamic memory allocation. This solution also has the advantage that your code will be portable, as you are no longer using platform-specific functions.

Comment: 4. use `std::array<char*, 2>` and `std::thread` instead. No need to allocate an array dynamically, `std::array` can be copied by value into the `std::thread`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, you are right that this would be the modern C++ approach to solving the problem. I have therefore edited my answer to refer to your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think the reason that I cannot see the data on the other thread is that each thread has its own stack so I must copy the data onto the heap before I pass it over. What I did was malloc(sizeof(argStruct)) and use that as the argument.

Comment: @lemon: Generally, there is nothing wrong with one thread accessing another thread's stack (except maybe a slight performance decrease due to [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)) as long as the lifetime of the accessed object has not expired. Therefore, it would for example not be a problem to pass a local variable of `main` to the other thread, as long as the thread is guaranteed to terminate before the function `main` exits. In your case, the problem was passing an object of insufficient lifetime.

Comment: @lemon: Note that `malloc` is generally not used in C++ programs, but only in C programs. You might want to consider using `new` instead. Generally, I wouldn't recommend mixing `new` and `malloc` in a C++ program, unless you have a specific reason to do so. In future, if you prefer C-only answers and not C++ answers, you might want to tag your questions `c` instead of `c++`. But please don't change the tag of this question, because this would partially invalidate my answer.